# How do I deploy a 3-tier architecture C# solution?

Tags: c#, remoting, 3-tier

Please forgive the newbie question.  I've spent the last three hours researching this, and I can't quite find the right answer, or perhaps I just don't believe it's as simple as it looks.

I need to deploy an application such that an application on the server-side does the heavy lifting, database wise, and the client-side version is fairly lightweight.

I have built a Data Access Layer class library (or at least a dll) that does all the heavy lifting.  I have built a Windows Forms application that could serve as the lightweight client. They see each other. They talk to each other. They work happily together.

I'm kind of hoping all I need to do is put the dll on the server, point the reference to it in the client, and all will be well.  The dll will run its code on the server, using server resources, and the client will run on the client.  It's what the various websites seem to suggest, but it looks too simple.

Do I need to configure something like remoting on the server?  Do I need to use System.Runtime.Remoting for something?  Or is it really as simple as it looks?

Again, please forgive so basic a question.

Comment: you can't just deploy an architecture, you must  build "using" an architecture.

Comment: No, it is not __quite__ as simple. You need a server-side application to run youu DLL code, that your client/desktop app talks to and which can itself talk with the DBMS. Talk points toward an Interface between client and server app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are trying to do is build Client/Server application,
where you have

---

Client

client domainDomain

---

server Domain

Dal

Data

---

you will need to enstablish http conntection between client domain and server domain .
the common way to do this is using WCF
[Explain the different tiers of 2 tier & 3 tier architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199176/explain-the-different-tiers-of-2-tier-3-tier-architecture)
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/642296/Hello-World-Basic-Server-Client-Example-of-WCF
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14493/WCF-Basic-Client-Server

oh and welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is exactly the information I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use System.Runtime.Remoting, but that is a deprecated technology, i suggest using WCF for communicating between the client and the server.